# iterating over a list of strings using knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following knockout markup although I'm getting a list of single characters rather than the values for some reason.  Can someone advise how to access the value correctly?  Many thanks, James

**Model**

```
var data = {"Article":{"Keywords":"United Kingdom|Regional Press campaign|Public Relations|Europe|Wales|Healthcare PR|aaaaaaaa|Ad campaign|bbbbbb|PR|Internal Communications"}}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Markup**

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'keyword-template', data: Article }"></div>

<div style="float: left">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Keywords"/>
</div>

<ul data-bind="foreach: Keywords">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the whole string is treated as an array and `foreach` is interpreted as for each character in the sting.
How about `<ul data-bind="foreach: Keywords.split('|')">`? (Haven't tested it)

Comment: it works, you just need to write `<ul data-bind="foreach: Keywords().split('|')">` http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/ the `()` is missing.